# comparison of references to generic classes

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Main {
    static class A {};

    static class B {};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> r1 =  new A().getClass();
        Class<?> r2 =  new B().getClass();

        boolean a = (r1 == r2); //it is ok
        boolean b = (new A().getClass() == new B().getClass()); //compilation error
    }
}
```

r1 is reference to type `Class<A>`, and r2 is reference to type `Class<B>`. I guess it is not correct to compare them. But compiler does not produce error in string " `boolean a = (r1 == r2);`" Why? How it works in terms of generics type safety?

For example, you can not compare "`boolean c = (new ArrayList<String>() == new ArrayList<Integer>());`", the compiler says 'incomparable types'.

Comment: If you want to check the class of an object, use `instanceof`.

Comment: Did you mean to include `.getClass()` in the last paragraph's comparison?

Comment: But you can't compare them in this way that the OP intends to

Comment: Use `instanceof` to compare instances (objects). You can do `(r1 == r2)` because are references of `Class<?>` and compiler can't figure out which classes are.

Comment: <<If you want to check the class of an object, use instanceof.                                      My question is from interview. This question about comparison "new A().getClass() == new B().getClass()"

Answer (score 4):

`r1` and `r2` may contain a reference of any `Class` instance, and therefore they may contain a reference to the same `Class`. Therefore the compiler allows this comparison.

When you compare the bound Class instances in - `new A().getClass() == new B().getClass()` - the compiler knows they are not of the same type, and therefore doesn't allow it.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give a reference to java standard or maybe another resource to read in depth about assignment and comparison wildcard generics?

Answer (score 1):

First - You can not compare classes by using there references only. If you want to check classes is of same type you have to use `instanceof` operator in java.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are comparing a reference to a Class with a reference to another Class.

In the second case you are comparing a reference to an object of type A with a reference to an object of type B which is not allowed.

From the [The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf):

> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of
>   either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion
>   (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be
>   unequal.

In the first case, Class casts to Cast, but in the second case, neither B casts to A, nor A casts to B.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to find out if a class is of a certain type you will need to do something like the following:

```
public class Main {
    static class A {};

    static class B {};

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        A objA = new A();
        B objB = new B();

        if (objA instanceof A) {
          System.out.println("objA is an instance of A);
        }
        if (objB instanceof B) {
          System.out.println("objB is an instance of B);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you check classes are of certain type by using the instanceof operator in Java.